# How to wrap a stream into async , make it wait for a name resolution before starting the stream

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm currently doing a bot that receives a youtube url, and technically it must process the video and convert it into mp3. Problem is that the stream is starting before the url is assigned so it returns an error

```
videoUrl = ""; //this is determined by the last bot.onText function, thats where its asigned
var saveLocation = "";

function saveName(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => getInfo(videoUrl).then(info => {
         saveLocation = "./"+info.items[0].title+".mp3";

         resolve();
     }))

 }
 stream = ytdl(videoUrl) //Problem is that this doesn't wait for that assignment to finish so videoUrl is empty, and I'm not sure how to implement an async there that awaits for the resolution


 async function convert(){
     const data = await saveName();
     new ffmpeg({ source: stream, nolog: true }).toFormat('mp3').audioBitrate(320).on('end', function() {
         console.log('file has been converted successfully');
         })
         .on('error', function(err) {
         console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
         })
         .saveToFile(saveLocation); 
 }




 bot.onText(/^(http(s)??\:\/\/)?(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu.be\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])+/gm, (msg) => {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, msg.text)
    videoUrl = msg.text; //this is where the asignmenet should happen
    convert();
});
```

This is my interpretation of how the await should work for the stream, but it doesn't work properly

```
    videoUrl = "";
var saveLocation = "";

function saveName(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => getInfo(videoUrl).then(info => {
         saveLocation = "./"+info.items[0].title+".mp3";

         resolve();
     }))

 }
 async function streaming(){  //made it async
    const data = await saveName();
    stream = ytdl(videoUrl)
 }



 async function convert(){
     const data = await saveName();
     streaming();  //it should be resolved by the time saveName is processed, so it shold start the stream, but it wont
     new ffmpeg({ source: stream, nolog: true }).toFormat('mp3').audioBitrate(320).on('end', function() {
         console.log('file has been converted successfully');
         })
         .on('error', function(err) {
         console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
         })
         .saveToFile(saveLocation); 
 }




 bot.onText(/^(http(s)??\:\/\/)?(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu.be\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])+/gm, (msg) => {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, msg.text)
    videoUrl = msg.text;
    convert();
});
```

Comment: What is `ytld()` function ?

Comment: I'm presuming (there isn't a [mcve] here) that you just add an `await` like you do in various other places where you want to unwrap the promise.

Comment: @Weedoze part of the ytdl-core npm package. It streams a youtube video given a link , in my case its streaming it to the convert() function, in the new ffmpeg({ source:stream .....

Comment: Added a comment where the asingement should happen

Comment: @Liam I edited and tried to add the await to the streaming function, but it wont work tho

Comment: you need to put await before streaming()

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo thanks, that solved it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in `saveName` you resolve your return promise to undefined. It should be `resolve(saveLocation);`.

Secondly, if you want `stream` to be created after `videoUrl` is set, then simply move the `stream` construction line below the `videoUrl` assignment line.

```
// change this:

stream = ytdl(videoUrl); // obviously videoUrl will be undefined.

...

bot.onText(..., (msg) => {
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, msg.text)
  videoUrl = msg.text; //this is where the asignmenet should happen
  convert();
});

// into:

...

bot.onText(..., (msg) => {
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, msg.text)
  videoUrl = msg.text; //this is where the asignmenet should happen
  stream = ytdl(videoUrl)
  convert();
});
```